# How to use 'concern with' and 'concern for'

Tags: prepositions

Is the following sentence grammatically correct? 
'Liberals have a concern with individual liberty'

Or, should it be 'liberals have a concern for individual liberty'? And, more generally, what is the difference between *concern with* and *concern for*?

Comment: May be try this: Liberals are concerned about individual liberty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a subtle difference.

> Liberals have a concern with individual liberty.

means that liberals have an interest in the subject of individual liberty.

> Liberals have a concern for individual liberty.

means that liberals are positively interested in, and generally wish to promote individual liberty or its protection.

In general, to have a "concern with X" means to be interested in the general subject of X, one way or another, while to have a "concern for X" means to be infavor of or supportive of X, at least to some degree.